# text_field de rails 4 separado por coma y almacenarlo en la base de datos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo los siguientes modelos en rails

```
payment_supplier.rb
class PaymentSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folio_has_payment_suppliers
  has_many :folios, through: :folio_has_payment_suppliers, dependent: :destroy
end

folio_has_payment_supplier.rb
class FolioHasPaymentSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :folio
  belongs_to :payment_supplier
end

folio.rb
class Folio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folio_has_payment_suppliers
  has_many :payment_suppliers, through: :folio_has_payment_suppliers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Si hago pruebas desde la consola, la informacion se almacena correctamente

```
rails c --sandbox

ps = PaymentSupplier.new
ps.folio_ids
=> []
ps.folio_ids = [1, 4]
=> [1, 4]
ps.hotel_id = 87
ps.cantidad = 2500
ps.save
ps.folios (Me muestra los 2 folios almacenados, es decir me hace la union bien)
```

Mi problema es cuando paso esto a mi partial payment_supplier#_form.html.erb, guardo los datos y me guarda solo el primer valor del input, si yo pongo ej. 1,4,7,10 solo me almacena el 1, deduzco que porque para el input los valores los lee como string, y en la consola yo le pase los valores como un array [1, 4], asi que hago un ligero cambio a mi modelo

```
class PaymentSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folio_has_payment_suppliers
  has_many :folios, through: :folio_has_payment_suppliers, dependent: :destroy

  serialize :folio_ids, Array

  def folio_ids=(ids)
    self.folio_ids = ids.split(',')
  end
end
```

Segun lo que he leido, lo que busco es folio_ids separarlo por comas y almacenarlo, pero cuando agrego esta ultima modificacion a mi model, y hago el submit en el proyecto la aplicacion se cuelga, revisando en la consola obtengo esto

```
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/models/payment_supplier.rb:11:in `folio_ids='
  app/controllers/egr/payment_suppliers_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Comment: si estás haciendo la misma pregunta en ambas versiones de S.O., [al menos referencia a la pregunta en inglés o pon el link](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/93/213), porque si no haces eso, alguien (como yo) puede tratar de contestar tu pregunta sin saber que tu pregunta ya fue contestada. Recuerda que al otro lado del teclado hay alguien usando su tiempo para contestar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Ok amigo y de verdad una disculpa, en mi desesperacion trate de obtener ayuda por diferentes medios, de verdad no quise insultar ni mucho menos malgastar el tiempo de alguien. De cualquier forma tratare de hacer eso que me comentas, si te soy sincero era mi primer post en esta pagina, siempre habia leido y encontrado las respuestas que necesitaba de otros, pero esta vez no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion que encontre fue la siguiente, mi modelo payment_supplier.rb

```
class PaymentSupplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :hotel

  # Assosiations many to many
  has_many :folio_has_payment_suppliers
  has_many :folios, through: :folio_has_payment_suppliers, dependent: :destroy

  serialize :folio_ids, Array
  attr_accessor :folio_ids_text

  def folio_ids_text=(ids)
    self.folio_ids = ids.split(",").map(&:strip) # added map(&:strip)
  end
end
```

Y en mi partial tengo payment_supplier#_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :folio_ids_text, :class => 'form-control' %>
```

Mi controller queda de la siguiente forma

```
def create
  @pagoProvedor = PaymentSupplier.new(ps_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @pagoProvedor.save
      format.html { redirect_to [ "egr", @pagoProvedor ], notice: 'El gasto ha sido creado' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pagoProvedor}
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @pagoProvedor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  def ps_params
    params.require(:payment_supplier).permit(..., :folio_ids_text)
  end
```

Comment: deberías marcar como resuleta tu pregunta, para que no quede como que aun necesitas ayuda.

Comment: No se como se hace eso, si me orientas, te lo agradeceria muchisimo

Comment: tienes que pinchar el tick que aparece a la izquierda de la respuesta que te solucionó la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info y mil disculpas por contestar hasta ahorita, es solo que no me habia conectado jeje, ya indique lo que me comentas

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no deberías redefinir `folio_ids=`, ya que eso lo genera rails para manejar las relaciones con los otros modelos. De hecho en tu redefinición entraste en un loop infinito que es lo que te genera el error:

```
def folio_ids=(ids)
  self.folio_ids = ids.split(',')
end
```

Otra cosa, ¿cual es la intención de `serialize :folio_ids, Array`? si fue para transformar de string a array, no es lo adecuado. El objetivo de `serialize` es para convertir cualquier objeto en String para luego guardarlos en la bd, lo cual no creo sea este el caso (imagino no tienes un campo `folio_ids` en la tabla `payment_suppliers`). 
Otra cosa, ¿por que te llega un string en vez de un arreglo? Se supone que rails debería serializar los parámetros que llegan a través del request (si compartes el código del controlador, ayudaría). 
En caso que sea inevitable que ingrese un string para folio_ids, podrías setearlo a través de un `attr_accessor`, algo como:

```
    attr_accessor :folio_string

    def folio_string=(ids)
      self.folio_ids = ids.split(',') if ids.is_a? String
    end
```

Comment: Si tienes razon, en el foro en ingles me ayudaron, la verdad es que llevo apenas 6 meses con rails y hay algunas cosas y conceptos que desconozco, mi idea era utilizar token inputs, el codigo que tenia era un fragmento de un video de railscast, pero no pude hecharlo a andar. Al final hice algo parecido a lo que comentas aunque un tanto diferente, muchas gracias de todas formas